# mark row in data frame as "TRUE" if specific number inside group appear

Tags: r, select, row, conditional-statements

I asked you similar question before and change it now vice versa?
I would like to find rows inside groups in which defined number appear for last time, but if this number don't appear in the group than the next highest number will be used.

The data looks like this:

```
group <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")
value <- c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2)
dat <- data.frame(group, value)
dat
```

First I would like to search if the group has value 3 and if yes the row with last number 3 in the group is mark as "TRUE", if there is no number 3 in the group than look for first number 2 and so on. At the end each group has only one "TRUE". So the "RESULT" column should be the result on my question.
I hope that the question is more understandable this time and thank you in advance.

Expected result:

```
 group <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")
 value <- c(1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2)
 RESULT <- c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE")
 target <- data.frame(group, value, RESULT)
 target
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

```
f <- function(v) replace(logical(length(v)), 
                         which(v == max(v) & !duplicated(v, fromLast=TRUE)), 
                         TRUE)
transform(dat, GOAL=as.logical(ave(value, group, FUN=f)))
#    group value  GOAL
# 1      a     1 FALSE
# 2      a     3  TRUE
# 3      a     2 FALSE
# 4      a     1 FALSE
# 5      b     1 FALSE
# 6      b     1 FALSE
# 7      b     2  TRUE
# 8      b     1 FALSE
# 9      c     2 FALSE
# 10     c     3 FALSE
# 11     c     3  TRUE
# 12     c     2 FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

```
is.first.max <- function(x) seq_along(x) == which.max(x)
is.last.max  <- function(x) rev(is.first.max(rev(x)))
transform(dat, RESULT = as.logical(ave(value, group, FUN = is.last.max)))
```